# Dynamically inject HTML entity escaped for CSS via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css, fonts, escaping

I'm attempting to dynamically create a list of HTMLElements with `data-*` attributes that correspond to different HTML Entities, to be then picked up by CSS and used as pseudo element content like so:

```
li:after {
  content: attr(data-code);
}
```

The problem with this is that for `attr()` to properly render the actual entity, rather than the literal code is to [prefix said code with `&#x`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451553/css-data-attribute-new-line-character-pseudo-element-content-value#answer-16452853) - your typical `\` doesn't work.

So the desired output HTML is something like so: `<li data-code="&#xENTITY"></li>`. When added directly to HTML, this works exactly as expected in relation to my CSS rule. The escaped entity is placed on the page in an `:after` psuedo element and rendered as the entity icon.

Here's where things get curious...

As stated earlier, I'm trying to create and inject these `li`s **dynamically** through JavaScript (iterating through a list), and that's where the snag happens.

```
  var entities = [{code: '&#x1F602'}, ...];
  for (var i = 0; i < entitites.length; i++) {
    var entity = entitites[i],
        listItem = document.createElement('li');

    listItem.setAttribute('data-code', entity.code);
    list.appendChild(listItem);
  }
```

The `li` is correctly added to the DOM with the properly formatted entity set so it gets picked up by my CSS rule. However, rather than rendering the entity icon, the code is shown!

[image]

Note in the image above, the first item rendered is the HTML explicitly on the page. The second item is injected via JS (using the exact same code), then given an `:after` element by CSS. Chrome's web inspector even renders it differently!

[image]

Even curiouser still is that I can edit the HTML via WebInspector and inject the escaped `data-*` attribute manually - Chrome **STILL** renders the correct icon!

[image]

I'm at a loss here, so any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HTML entity notation will only be parsed by an HTML parser. If your `data-code` attributes are "born" in JavaScript, then you need to use the *JavaScript* notation for getting the Unicode characters you want. Instead of `&#x263A;` for a smiley face, in JavaScript you use `\u263A` (a backslash, a lower-case "u", and four hex digits).

Whether your `data-code` attributes are coded directly into your HTML source (with HTML entity notation) or else created in JavaScript (with JavaScript notation), by the time the attribute value is part of the DOM, it's Unicode.

Now, things get more complicated when you have characters outside the 16-bit range, because JavaScript is kind-of terrible at dealing with that. You can look up your code point(s) at http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/ and that'll give you the "C/C++/Java" UTF-16 code pair you need. For example, your "tears of joy" face is the pair `"\uD83D\uDE02"`.

Comment: This works for a regular line smiley, but not for the extended "emoji" set documented here: http://apps.timwhitlock.info/unicode/inspect/hex/1F602 - Perhaps this is another issue specific to this charset?

Comment: @JordanForeman I just finished updating the question - see the edit.