# Semantic-UI: Add line break in tooltip

Tags: css, semantic-ui

I want to have line breaks in my tooltip:

```
<span data:data-tooltip="line 1 ...\n 
                              line 2 ...">
```

I tried several proposals from here:
[Add line break within tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3340802/add-line-break-within-tooltips)

Nothing did the trick. I use it without Javascript (v.2.2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use `data-html` instead of `data-tooltip` with a `<br/>` tag.

```
<div class="ui icon button" data-html="<p>First line <br/> Second line</p>">
  <i class="add icon"></i>
</div>
```

This solution needs Javascript, see [PEN](https://codepen.io/pme123/pen/JpWEyG?editors=1111)

Comment: thanks, I take this solution. As this needs Javascript,  I edited your answer to accept it

Answer (score 5):

If you require to use the no JS version of tooltip, you may adjust the `width` of the tooltip and set the `white-space` to `normal`. [PEN](https://codepen.io/gibinealias/pen/XZMJbj)

Answer (score 2):

Because i found this first via google, its good to complete:

You can also use `&#xa;` in combination with `white-space: pre;` like stated here:
[CSS data attribute new line character & pseudo-element content value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451553/css-data-attribute-new-line-character-pseudo-element-content-value/16452853#16452853)

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to @terraloader's answer, but I wanted to give it more context.

**This is the best non-Javascript solution for adding a line break in a Semantic UI tooltip.**

Add the following rule to your stylesheet:

```css
[data-tooltip]::after {
    white-space: pre;
}
```

And then, in your `data-tooltip` attribute, use the `&#xa;` *

Here's how:

```html
<span data-tooltip="If you want to remove&#xa;this item from the&#xa;list, click here.">
    <i class="red delete icon"></i>
</span>
```

<sub>* This is the HTML-Encoded Line Feed character (using a hexadecimal value). You can also use the decimal notation `&#10;`. Either way, they are functionally equivalent to `\n` which is a Line Feed.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what version of Semantic-ui you could jsut update the main style sheet; looks like min has `white-space:norap` in it. Here I have updated it to `white-space:pre` and then will try using the 
 in line in the tool tip text:

```
[data-tooltip]:after{
    pointer-events:none;
    content:attr(data-tooltip);
    position:absolute;
    text-transform:none;
    text-align:left;
    white-space:pre;
    font-size:1rem;
    border:1px solid #d4d4d5;
    line-height:1.4285em;
    max-width:none;
    background:#fff;
    padding:.833em 1em;
    font-weight:400;
    font-style:normal;
    color:rgba(0,0,0,.87);
    border-radius:.28571429rem;
    box-shadow:0 2px 4px 0 rgba(34,36,38,.12),0 2px 10px 0 rgba(34,36,38,.15);
    z-index:1
}
```