# CSS pseudo-element content value with line-break via attr inserted by Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

There's a similar discussion here : [CSS data attribute new line character & pseudo-element content value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451553/css-data-attribute-new-line-character-pseudo-element-content-value)

Problem is, this didn't work if the attr is set via  Javascript

I understand that `\A` doesn't work in attr, but now `&#xa;` doesn't work on attr via Javascript, is there any way to get this working?

```js
const ele = document.getElementById('my-ele')
ele.classList.add('loading');
ele.setAttribute('loading-text', 'Your file is being generated...&#xa;This may take some minutes');
```

```css
.loading::after {
  content: attr(loading-text);
}
```

```html
<div id="my-ele"></div>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a plain newline character (`\n` in your JavaScript string), fix the `getElementById()` call (get rid of "#"), and add `white-space: pre-wrap;` to the CSS.

```js
const ele = document.getElementById('my-ele')
ele.classList.add('loading');
ele.setAttribute('loading-text', 'Your file is being generated...\nThis may take some minutes');
```

```css
.loading::after {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  content: attr(loading-text);
}
```

```html
<div id="my-ele"></div>
```

Comment: Wow... full circle huh

Answer (score 6):

It's the line feed character `&#10`. `\u000A` is the JS equivalent and will make it work.

```js
const ele = document.getElementById('my-ele'); //removed the #
ele.classList.add('loading');
ele.setAttribute('loading-text', 'Your file is being generated...\u000AThis may take some minutes');

const ele2 = document.getElementById('my-ele2'); //removed the #
ele2.classList.add('loading');
ele2.setAttribute('loading-text', 'Your file is being generated...\nThis may take some minutes'); //as suggested by Pointy also works!
```

```css
.loading::after {
white-space: pre-wrap;
  content: attr(loading-text);
}
```

```html
<div id="my-ele"></div>

<div id="my-ele2"></div>
```