# Line break inside <a href> tag

Tags: html, wordpress, line-breaks, magnific-popup

Little bit of the situation. I'm using Wordpress Magnific popup plugin and it takes the picture from media library. On the picture I have a title, alt and some caption, and when i enter it on my page then 
 outside of the lightbox I get this code when inspecting it. The problem is that I can't get any html to work with it. I figured it must be because its inside  tag. I'm wondering if theres a possibility to make it take html in it since i need to use the line breaks in it?

`<figure> <a href="https://somepage.com/somepage/image.jpeg" data-rel="lightbox-gallery-1234" data-magnific_type="image" data-rl_title="Some Title" data-rl_caption="Caption for the picture and some more text" title="Some title"> <img src="https://somepage.com/somepage/image.jpeg" data-link="https://somepage.com/somepage/image.jpeg"> </a></figure>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found an answer to my problem. Added
white-space:pre-wrap;
to CSS and `&#13;` works as line breaker

Answer (score 0):

Check this question: [CSS data attribute new line character & pseudo-element content value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16451553/css-data-attribute-new-line-character-pseudo-element-content-value)

The same is going to work for you too.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've tried this and yet it still doesn't work. It just absorbs the &#xa; element in the text and does absolutely nothing about it. The element also dissapears from the caption when I open the lightbox